# The upload_max_filesize in php.ini on my shared server is not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to upload files on my shared server but i am not able to do that when my file is bigger than 2MB. I know the problem is the upload_max_filesize in php.ini but the thing is that on the php.ini file its already 8M. Now i dont know what should i do. Since i am using shared hosting i dont have any access of php.ini file. I can just see its reference. I tried writing my own php.ini file in the public_html folder like this:

```
upload_max_filesize = 5M
```

And wrote .htaccess file outside public_html like:

```
    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
suPHP_ConfigPath /path_to_homedirectory/public_html/php.ini
</IfModule>
```

but this is not working either. Can you suggest some other way or if i had done any mistake please let me know. Any help would be appriciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to go through .htaccess way set below vars in your root .htaccess file.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 8M
php_value post_max_size 8M
```

But make sure you have permission to set php_value.

And if you want to go php way, you may try ini_set but I am unsure about it.

```
ini_set('variable_name','value');
```